# How to Ping multiple IP addresses AND only save to file if ping failed OR latency is greater than X milliseconds? (Bash or PowerShell)

Tags: bash, powershell, ping

I want to write a simple PowerShell/Bash script which will run in the background on one productive PC that checks every 1-5 seconds if every chosen member is pingable. If not, the result should be saved to a .txt file with timestamp and IP address. The result should be also saved to .txt file if the latency is greater than e.g. 30 milliseconds.

I already have

```
ping -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | 
    ForEach-Object {"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date), $_} > C:\Users\xy\pingtest.txt
```

but this saves every output to the .txt file which won't help me very much.

How can I work from this solution to my desired solution?

Comment: How do you derive "every chosen member"?

Comment: we have 5 areas where there are 10-20 members in the area specific network. some of them make problems lately and we want to narrow it down to where the problem could lie. So we pick the members, that are problematic lastly and want to log the "bad" events, to get more insight. @RamanSailopal

Comment: See about `if` statements as a start

Comment: @Abraham Zinala, thank you. The only problem, I am facing is, I don't know how to access the latency and if the ping was successful. As soon as I know, how to access these parameters, the rest is easy

Comment: Start from [`Test-Connection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Okay, so I am at: `while($True){ 
 $COMPUTERs="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
 ForEach ($COMPUTER in $COMPUTERs) 
 {if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
  
  {write-host "cannot reach $computer"
  }
  
  
  
 else {
  
 Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1
 } 
 Start-Sleep 1
 } 
 }`

Comment: But I am not able to access the Time field. In fact, i am not able to access any field, except the ipv4adress. All other fields just output blank spaces without any values. If there's a way to access the "Time(ms)" field, I will be able to solve the problem and happy to post the solution.
Select "Time(ms)" does not work as it just outputs blank spaces. When using the "-ExpandProperty flag, it leads to an error, that the "Time(ms)-property can't be found"

Comment: Okay, I used the "get-Member" flag incorrectly which lead to an errormsg, when I wanted to find out the parameter names. Now I got it. The flag should be `Select -ExpandProperty ResponseTime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this script, add permission to execute `chmod +x myScript`
run it in terminal with `watch -n 5 ./myScript`

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
list=(192.168.1.{0..12})
my_time=0.7
file=fileName_"$(date)".txt

for ip in "${list[@]}"; do
    ping -c 2 "$ip" >ipOutput.txt
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        cat <ipOutput.txt >>"$file"
        echo "error: $ip $(date) [saving to file]"
    else
        get_time=$(cat <ipOutput.txt | grep avg | awk -F '/' '{print $5}')
        if (($(echo "$get_time" '>='"$my_time" | bc -l))); then
            cat <ipOutput.txt >>"$file"
            echo "$ip OK, MORE time: $get_time milliseconds [saving to file]"
        else
            echo "$ip : OK, less than $my_time milliseconds [$get_time]"
        fi
    fi
done
rm ipOutput.txt
```

#### Explaining Answer

**Create an array of IP's addresses**

```
list=(192.168.1.{0..12})
```

you can save in a file a list of iddress to ping and then save it in this variable`list`. This is a bash sequence expression `{0..12}` fills the numbers within a range, this case,from 0 to 12. End result is `list=(192.168.1.0 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2...)`

This can be a list of string[domains], example:  and works fine

```
 list=("amazon.com" "google.com" "target.com")
```

**create variables:**

```
file=fileName_"$(date)".txt
```

`$(date)` this commands adds date to a file[file_with_errors]

**iterate array `list` of ip's**

```
for ip in "${list[@]}"; do
```

this lines iterates an array with name `list` access all items with `[@]`, this is a special sintax for bash.

**ping each IP 2 times and save it to file**

```
ping -c 2 "$ip" >ipOutput.txt
```

`-c` argument, pings an ip a specific number of times, in this case 2 times. After ping, save that OUTPUT to a file[ipOutput.txt] instead of console with `>`, this save the OUTPUT **ONCE** for each new IP.

**check the OUTPUT from PING and if error exist  save it to a file**

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    cat <file.txt >>"$file"
    echo "error: $ip $(date) [saving to file]"
```

`$?` prints the last output from the last command[PING], and because it's not equal to 0, this means error. `cat< ipOutput.txt` It shows the content from OUTPUT of PING, and then redirects that data to the variable `$file`[your_log_file] with `>>`, this means appends[NO overwrite]. `echo` prints the text format in terminal

**if not error Continue to ELSE statement**

```
else
    get_time=$(cat <ipOutput.txt | grep avg | awk -F '/' '{print $5}')
```

`get_time` saves the average time that took to ping ip address, in milliseconds.
`awk` awk is a program for checking columns in text.
`-F '/'` argument tells `awk` which delimeter to use, in this case `/`. `{print $5}` grabs the **number** of milliseconds.

output that grabs **grep** and **awk**

- rtt min/**avg**/max/mdev = 1.637/**1.693**/1.749/0.056 ms

**Check how long it takes to ping ip address**

```
if (($(echo "$get_time" '>='"$my_time" | bc -l))); then
```

I reckon the weird of `(( ))` but for comparison do it. `$(commands)` is for writing commands and pipes in this case `echo, >=, |`. The operator `>=` has to have `' '`. `| bc -l` is for comparing floats in bash.

> *This is just an IF STATEMENT, but bash needs special sintax for comparing two floats.*

**save to file because took more TIME to ping of desire time**

```
cat <ipOutput.txt >>"$file".txt
echo "$ip OK, but took MORE time: $get_time milliseconds [saving to file]"  
else
    echo "$ip : OK, less than $my_time milliseconds [$get_time]"
```

`else` everything was ok and NOT saved to file but show ok STATUS in terminal

**remove file ipOutput.txt**

```
rm ipOutput.txt
```

This file was used to save the output for each ip with `ping` command. This file overwrites the data each new ip, so you can retrieve the info more easy with `grep` and `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

This is, what does the trick for me

```
$processName = "PROCESSNAME"
$basePath = "~\Documents\PingTests"
$archivePath = "~\Documents\PingTests\Archive"

# Set temporary timestamp, which will be used to check, if one day has passed,
# so that the moving and removing of the files will be done just once a day
$dateTemp = (get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy)

# Function to get the current timestamp in the desired format
function Get-TimeStamp {

    return "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)

}

# Create the basePath for the logs
If(!(test-path $basePath)){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $basePath
}

# Create an archivePath for the logs
If(!(test-path $archivePath)){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $archivePath
}



while($True){
    # Check, if the desired process is running. This is crucial for the correct execution of the script.
    # Only in this case, the current pc is the productive one that has connection to the modbus members.
    $process  = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -eq $processName}
    if($process){
        # List of modbus members, that one wants to monitor
        $COMPUTERs="IP-LIST"
        
        # For-Loop that checks every member in "COMPUTERs"
        ForEach ($COMPUTER in $COMPUTERs){
            # In case the member is not pingable, write it to the .txt file
                if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)){
                # Console output for debugging purposes (not relevant, if execution is done via Task scheduler)
                write-host "cannot reach $computer"
                
                # Call of function "Get-TimeStamp"
                $timestamp = (Get-TimeStamp)
                
                # Write results to file
                "TIMESTAMP:      $timestamp, cannot reach IP-ADRESS:      $computer" | 
                out-file -filepath "~\Documents\PingTests\ping_$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy).log" -append -width 200
            }
            
            # If the member is pingable, check the latency
            else {
                $Testoutput = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 | Select -ExpandProperty ResponseTime
                Write-Host $Testoutput
                
                # If latency is greater than 30 milliseconds, write the event to the .log file (Testoutput 
                # has been typecasted, that Powershell can check, if the value is greater than 30ms)
                if([int]$Testoutput -gt 30){
                    
                    # Call of function "Get-TimeStamp"
                    $timestamp = (Get-TimeStamp)
                    
                    # Console output for debugging purposes (not relevant, if execution is done via Task scheduler)
                    write-host $timestamp "," $computer "," $Testoutput
                    
                    # Write results to file
                    "TIMESTAMP:      $timestamp,              IP-ADRESS:      $computer ,             LATENCY:      $Testoutput" | 
                    out-file -filepath "~\Documents\PingTests\ping $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy).log" -append -width 200
                }
            }
        }
        
        # If one day has passed, move files that are older than 7 days to the archive folder and
        # remove files in archive folder, that are older than 30 days
        if(!($dateTemp -eq (get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy))){
            
            # Set dateTemp variable to current day
            $dateTemp = (get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy)
            
            # Move files
            $date1 = (get-date).AddDays(-7)
            get-childitem ~\Documents\PingTests\ping *.log | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date1} | 
            move-item -destination ~\Documents\PingTests\Archive
            
            # Remove files
            $date2 = (get-date).AddDays(-30)
            get-childitem ~\Documents\PingTests\Archive\ping *.log | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date2} | 
            Remove-Item -Force
        }
        
        # Wait one second until the next execution
        Start-Sleep 1
    }
}
```

Comment: answer for bash below 
@InfiProg